# Nexmo API credentials error

Tags: laravel-5, vonage

I am working on an sms feature by the Nexmo package.
However I encountered an error which is:

> Please provide Nexmo API credentials. Possible combinations: api_key + api_secret, api_key + signature_secret, private_key + application_id, api_key + api_secret + private_key + application_id, api_key + signature_secret + private_key + application_id

[image]

Though I already filled up my `.env` and `config/nexmo.php` files.

Comment: Which keys have you set in your `.env`?

Comment: @leggetter the values on my nexmo dashboard /getting-started-guide, got it from my key and secret field.
i tried the send an sms API and it works. using those credentials ofcourse

Comment: @leggetter Currently using laravel 5.5.40 by the way. 
Already tried your article but still didn't work for me.

Comment: Can you just use one `.env` or `config/nexmo.php`? Also can list all the steps you have followed for the integration?

Comment: This is already fixed. I created a new laravel installation and just had an issue perhaps on my xampp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just created a new Laravel project using the guide from the repo and got this new error message.

```
>cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

The repo is working fine and just my xampp is the issue.

My solution was as simple as: Follow this link: http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem Copy the entire page and save it in a: "cacert.pem"

Then in your php.ini file insert or edit the following line: curl.cainfo = "[pathtothisfile]\cacert.pem"

Comment: Hii @leonardeveloper i have added this certificate to my d drive and also add this line curl.cainfo = "D:\xampp\htdocs\cacert.pem" to php.ini and restart the server but i faced same error like you have faced.

Comment: if you face same error perhaps there's something wrong in the path or something.